# What does the zig-zag arrow in the System Flows Chart indicate?

Tags: flowchart

I have the following situation which is required to be depicted by a Systems Flow Chart:

[image]

My attempt at drawing these diagrams is to figure out the following four things:

1) Input= The Sales Transaction

2) Process= Verification of Credit Card

3) Output= Reciept

4) Stored Data= Prices, Product and Transaction Files

How do I involve the Central Computer?

The model answer to this problem is:

[image]

I've looked up several legends that describe the common symbols used in System Flowcharts, but I've never come across a circle and zig-zagged lines. I would like to know the proper definitions for these two symbols. As per my knowledge, they can't represent input, document or storage system. Then what are they?

Lastly, could anyone please share a resource for learning and practising System Flow Chart diagrams or maybe any heuristic that one can use to solve such problems?

Comment: It should be Telecomunication link. Im not sure so I dont post it as answer, but I'll do some research ;)

Answer (score 1):

So that zig-zag line is Communication link, found it [there](http://www.geocities.ws/shaileshpandeynec/cflowchart.pdf) (page 3), but it maybe depends on tool you are working with.

That zig-zag symbol  represents  the 
transmission  of  data  from  one  location  to 
another via communication lines.

Also that circle/elipse stands for the  beginning, 
end, or a point of interruption in a process or 
program.    Also  used  to  indicate  an  external 
party.

In your case it is external party.